# Check if player is on top of another node?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to allow my player to jump. However I cannot let him jump in mid-air so I need to check if it's standing on top of another node before applying an impulse.

How do other sprite-kit games normally do this?

---

Right now I'm trying two approaches, the first one is this one. It's great however I don't know how to tell if the node the player is touching is really below or to the side of the player.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var allowJump = false
    let bodies = player.physicsBody.allContactedBodies()
    for body : AnyObject in bodies {
        if let node = body.node {
            allowJump = true // Player is touching another node but we don't know where (the bottom of the player or it's sides)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the other approach, it's effective to tell if a contact started and also whether the contact is really with the ground (below the player) and not a wall or such. However I don't know how to tell when the player stops being on top of any nodes, because even if a contact ends he might still be contacting another node.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!){
    if(contact.bodyA.node.position.y < contact.contactPoint.y) {
        println("BodyA is on top of another node")
    }

    if(contact.bodyB.node.position.y < contact.contactPoint.y) {
        println("BodyB is on top of another node")
    }
}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!){
     if(contact.bodyA.node.position.y < contact.contactPoint.y) {
        println("BodyA is on no longer on top of BodyB")
    }

    if(contact.bodyB.node.position.y < contact.contactPoint.y) {
        println("BodyB is no longer on top of BodyA")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'm doing now however it doesn't let me know if the node it's touching is below/left/right. I could simply compare its position to my node however some nodes are hollow like edgeLoopFromPath or have different shapes.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var allowJump = false
    let bodies = player.physicsBody.allContactedBodies()
    for body : AnyObject in bodies {
        if let node = body.node { // Additionally check contactBitMask
            allowJump = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef  NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t, CNPhysicsCategory)
{
    CNPhysicsCategoryChick = 1,
    CNPhysicsCategoryEdge = 2,
    CNPhysicsCategoryStrawberry = 3,
};

@interface MyScene() <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@end


@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *strawberry;
    SKSpriteNode *chick;

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryEdge;
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
        self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;

        chick = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"chick"];
        [chick setScale:0.3];
        chick.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, chick.size.height/2);
        chick.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:chick.size];
        chick.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryChick;
        chick.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryEdge;
        chick.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
        [self addChild:chick];


        strawberry = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"strawberry"];
        strawberry.position = CGPointMake(chick.position.x, chick.position.y - chick.size.height/2 + strawberry.size.height/2);

        //You should make this hidden
        //strawberry.hidden = YES;

        strawberry.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(strawberry.size.width, strawberry.size.height)];
        strawberry.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryStrawberry;
        strawberry.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kNilOptions;
        strawberry.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsCategoryEdge;
        strawberry.physicsBody.density = 0.001;
        strawberry.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
        [self addChild:strawberry];

        SKPhysicsJointFixed *point = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:strawberry.physicsBody bodyB:chick.physicsBody anchor:CGPointZero];
        [self.physicsWorld addJoint:point];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [chick.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 60)];
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryEdge | CNPhysicsCategoryStrawberry)) {
        NSLog(@"In Contact");
    }
}

-(void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryEdge | CNPhysicsCategoryStrawberry)) {
        NSLog(@"Contact Is Lost");
    }
}


@end
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: the problem is that there might be a ledge, or some sort of box where the player can stand.

Comment: I see, so for a generic solution u should use SKPhysicsContactDelegate with -(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact method, there are many examples on web, I guess you can easily solve your problem now

Comment: I checked them, however they seem to fire when the contact started but I don't understand how to know if the nodes are touching inside the update() method. I'll add a bounty in a few moments!

Comment: My suggestion is to use didBeginContact and didEndContact methods to check whether the objects are touching each other, and if it is necessary use flags or performSelector inside those methods too

Comment: Hi Ahmet, I updated your answer with my current code. I managed to know if my player (or any node) get's on top of another. However I don't know how to precisely tell when the node is no longer on top of anything.

Comment: Hi @lisovaccaro, I solved your problem and added all the code with two images that I used in the project too. What I did is; added a chick(your player) and used a small strawberry. Strawberry is small and has negligible density, I used it for contact check purposes (cause you want to know whether is player's bottom is touching). And I added those two images by JointFix method, plus I also check whether they are in contact or not. Hope this time you it solves your problem, and let me know :)

Comment: Hi Ahmet I don't understand how would that let me know if the player is on top of the other node as opposed to next to it.

Comment: Hi @lisovaccaro , because you create another smaller size node respect to your player. And you make this node invisible then add it to the bottom of your player (think this like you are adding shoes). Because your node has smaller size and placed at the bottom of your player, now you can use your smaller node's contact delegate. Hope it is now more clear

Answer (score 1):

Update for **Swift 5**

```
guard let bodies = player.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies() else { return }
for body: SKPhysicsBody in bodies {
    if let node = body.node {
        if node.name == "ground" {
            isJumping = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **states** to accomplish this.

Lets say ur player can be in two states - 1. **touchingTheGround** 2. **inTheAir**

- Apply upward impulse on the player only if its state is **touchingTheGround** and change state to **inTheAir**
- When the player touches the ground set its state to **touchingTheGround**. Also at this point you can check that the angle made by the line passing through centre of player node and point of contact makes a -90 degree(*or around -90*) angle with +x axis.(*player landed on its feet*)
- If the player does **not** lands on its feet you can send the player to some other state and write different logic for that state.

To implement states I'll recommend using NS_ENUM

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. I think I need a function that really checks if the user is touching the ground, after all if he falls from a ledge with this logic the player would be touching the ground

Comment: hi sps, I'm really close to the solution. Please look at the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Add another node at the bottom of your player node (feet if you will) and use that for detecting collisions. Make this 'feet node' slightly narrower than your player so it won't trigger side collisions. When the feet have contacting bodies other than perhaps the player itself, you know it is standing on something.